# Synology ssh port receiving too many intrusion attacks, how to ban systematically?

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, synology

I have a synology NAS which I leave at home, and leave it open so I can access it remotely from the office.

One of the useful things to do is enable the ssh port so I can access it with my terminal. But the problem that comes with doing this is that the SSH port starts receiving so many login attempts, that the synology system ends up flooding me with alert e-mails.

I'm thinking there should be a way for the Synology system to ban access to a certain IP if it has already failed to log-in a certain number of times? This way the attack attempts would be much lower and I would not be flooded with emails.

Answer (score 1):

Synology has an Auto Block IP feature :

https://originwww.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/tutorials/615

That should sort you out.

What I'd recommend though is to configure your firewall to only allow access to port 22 from your works IP address (find the external IP address [here](http://groanmyip.com)) as it will eventually get ridiculous the number of IP's listed in auto block.

If you need to be more relaxed about allowing access to more than just your work IP then configure your firewall to block Chinese IP's. I use the [Wizcraft IP address lists](http://www.wizcrafts.net/chinese-blocklist.html), just lift the ranges out of their configurations (and remember to chuck them a quid or two for their help).